# How to implement a Mojolicious filter and raise an error message?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I have this filter:

```
use Net::IP;

sub create_inet {
    my( $self, $name, $value ) =  @_;

    $self->error( $name => [ 'create_inet', 'Bad INET', Net::IP::Error ] ), return
       unless my $ip =  Net::IP->new( $value );

    return $ip;
}
```

Which I add into my application like this

```
$app->validator->add_filter( inet => \&create_inet );
```

And in the controller's action I do this check

```
$c->validation->required( 'subnet', 'inet' );
```

But when the value for `subnet` is supplied in the wrong format I get the error `required` instead of the expected `Bad INET`.

The error is overridden [in `Mojolicious::Validator::Validation`](https://github.com/kraih/mojo/blob/master/lib/Mojolicious/Validator/Validation.pm#L88).

How to implement such a filter and raise an error if the supplied data is in the wrong format?

---

#### update

The `Mojolicious` app has two things I am interested in in this question:

- filter
- checker

The `filter` works on `{ input }` values and puts them into `{ output }` after formatting it. For an example, look at the [`trim` filter](https://metacpan.org/source/SRI/Mojolicious-7.31/lib/Mojolicious/Validator.pm#L43).

The `checker` just checks validity of the parameter and raises error if necessary.

In my approach I want to turn the input value into an object: `'1.2.3.4/32' -> Net::IP`. So `$self->param( 'subnet' )` will return a `Net::IP` object

I have two choices:

```
$self->required( 'subnet' )->inet;   #First
$self->required( 'subnet', 'inet' ); #Second (described in question)
```

To my mind the first would break encapsulation because `output` is changed directly:

```
$app->validator->add_check( inet => \&create_inet );

use Net::IP;

sub create_inet {
    my( $self, $name, $value ) =  @_;

    return Net::IP::Error
        unless my $ip =  Net::IP->new( $value );

    $self->output->{ $name } =  $ip; # Will this broke encapsulation?
    return;
}
```

In the second case the error message is lost.

Comment: What are `$app` and `$c`?

Comment: The purpose of `add_filter` is to massage the value before checks are applied. The filter is not where you raise a validation error. You need to `add_check` to check if the submitted value conforms to your criteria. The applicable checks for `subnet` are both `required` and your custom check.

Comment: On a separate note, you should consider updating your question to give more information so that people who do not already know what you are working on can understand it without the benefit of the dialogue between @Borodin and Simbabque.

Comment: @Borodin: in terms of Mojolicious the `$app` is a reference to application. and `$c` is controller class which handles current request.

Comment: did you kept the rule to return undef when the data is valid?

Comment: @TigranKhachikyan: thanks. Fixed

Comment: just for curiosity, can you please point how you fixed it?

Comment: @TigranKhachikyan: `return $ip`  -> `return;`